# Duplicate components because of layout in svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am in svelte kit and I have a component TopNav that has many custom properties such as clientPage (weather it is a client page or not) and I have the TopNav component in my root `+layout.svelte` like shown:

```html
<!-- /routes/+layout.svelte -->
<script>
    import TopNav from "@components/TopNav.svelte";
</script>
<TopNav noSpace />
<slot />
```

and one of my nested pages `/routes/app/+page.svelte`:

```html
<!-- /routes/app/+page.svelte -->
<script>
    import TopNav from "@components/TopNav.svelte";
</script>
<TopNav noSpace clientPage>
  TopNav with content
</TopNav>
```

and right now it compiles to something like:

```html
<!-- mock compiled code shiped to browser -->
<script>
    import TopNav from "@components/TopNav.svelte";
</script>
<TopNav noSpace />
<TopNav noSpace clientPage>
  TopNav with content
</TopNav>
```

Is there some way I could remove the first TopNav component in the layout or use something like `svelte:head` to change the way the first TopNav is displayed?

I have tried creating a layout file in `/app/` like so:

```html
<!-- /routes/app/+layout.svelte -->
<slot />
```

however it still compiles the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to group pages with specific layouts (using `(...)` in the directory name) and to break out of the layout chain (using `@`, optionally followed by the level to break to).

Though there is no way to skip the root layout. You probably can just make the root layout empty/remove the elements that cannot always exist and group everything outside `app` into a separate group with a different `TopNav` in its layout (groups do not affect the URL).

Something like:

```
src/routes/
├ app/
│ ├ +page.svelte
│ └ +layout.svelte
├ (default)/
│ ├ ...
│ ├ ...
│ ├ ...
│ └ +layout.svelte
└ +layout.svelte
```

See the [advanced layouts](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts) section of the documentation for details.